# Kube proxy load balance across machines

Tags: kubernetes, kube-proxy

My understanding is that Kube-proxy can load balance the services running across machines? Can someone confirm, that is what it is designed for..
Rgs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The kube-proxy ensures that traffic sent to a service is load balanced to one of the endpoints that implements that service.

Answer (score 2):

kube-proxy is more of a "load-spreader" than load-balancer.  It does not actively consider the target load, it just distributes incoming requests to backends in an approximately equal proportion.

From within a Kubernetes cluster it also implements a form of VIP, which redirects traffic for a virtual service to the backends for that service.

It should work across machines or on the same machine.